# How does one add a node or nodes to an existing YugaByte DB CE cluster?

Tags: database, distributed-system, yugabytedb

Using the steps documented in https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/public-clouds/aws/#manual-deployment we were able to create a 6-node, 3 availability zone (AZ) cluster using the community edition of YugaByte.

We now want to test expanding the cluster from 6 nodes to 9 nodes.

a) What is the procedure to add three mode nodes one in each AZ to this running cluster in YugaByte DB?

b) And, should the nodes be added with some recommended time interval in between or all at once?

c) And are any additional steps needed to trigger load balancing of existing tables to new nodes once the nodes are part of the cluster?

Could not find documentation related to above. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

a) Adding Nodes in an AZ aware manner

The new nodes should be prepared similarly to other nodes (as described in the link you posted) in terms of `ulimit` settings, data drive preparation, YugaByte DB software installation etc.

During cluster expansion, given that there's already enough nodes running the `yb-master` processes, the new nodes only need to run the `yb-tserver` process. The steps related to `yb-master` processes can be omitted when adding nodes to the cluster. [To read more about the role of the `yb-master` and `yb-tserver` process, see https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/architecture/concepts/universe/.]

When preparing the `yb-tserver` config file for the newly added nodes, be sure to set their placement info flags appropriately (the cloud/region/zone) which tells the system and its load-balancer the needed information about where each of the nodes is:

For example, for the first new node these flags might be something like:

```
--placement_cloud=aws
--placement_region=us-west
--placement_zone=us-west-2a
```

and for the other two nodes the `--placement_zone` might be say `us-west-2b` and `us-west-2c`.

You would have done something similar when setting up `yb-tserver` on the initial 6 nodes spread across the three AZs.

Starting those `yb-tserver`'s would be no different from the initial servers. For example:

```
~/tserver/bin/yb-tserver --flagfile ~/yb-conf/tserver.conf >& /mnt/d0/yb-tserver.out &
```

Note: The value for the master addresses gflag `tserver_master_addrs` in `tserver.conf` should be same as that of the existing `yb-tservers`. That's what ensures these nodes will seamlessly join the existing cluster.

b) The nodes can be added/started all at once. There is no need to add them one at time with some wait interval in between. The latter may actually cause data to be rebalanced/moved more times than necessary. When the system knows that it needs to go from a 6-node state to 9-node state all at once, it can more optimally get to the desired end state of a balanced cluster by doing only the required amount of data movement.

c) No additional steps are needed to trigger load-balancing! The system automatically rebalances the tablets (shards) in a rate limited manner to keep impact on the foreground application minimal. Currently, this per-node rate limit is controlled by the gflag `remote_boostrap_rate_limit_bytes_per_sec` and its default is 100 MB/sec. But depending on workload and bandwidth available this can be adjusted to a more aggressive or conservative setting. Note that this rebalancing is a background & online operation in YugaByte DB, and is done by copying compressed files from corresponding tablet leaders. Therefore, it is significantly lighter weight than eventually consistent databases (like Apache Cassandra or MongoDB) which have to do a logical (uncompressed) read of data from all peers.